# Correct layouts to use in this situation?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I'm completely new to Android development, and so I'm still a little confused as to which layouts to use in certain situations.

I need to recreate this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/BTcIgbS.png]

Where you have 2 lines of text (one above, one below) aligned next to an image. This is all within a card.

`Bold Text` and `Text` should be centered with each other vertically. `Subtext` should be `10dp` below the first line. The space between the lines of text and the image is `16dp`.

First I used only a `RelativeLayout` with an `ImageView` and 3 `TextView` in it, but that felt wrong and unorganized.

So then I tried this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MS9Pl.png

But I'm still not sure if this is the most correct way to do this.

What should I change?

Comment: Why don't you try constraint layout?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Set your "**Parent Layout**" as "**RelativeLayout**".

Inside this relative layout,  take an **ImageView** and set "**alignParentLeft**" property to true and also "**centreInparent**" to true.
Now, inside this **RelativeLayout**, take a **LinearLayout** with orientation set to **Veritical** and "toRightOf=@id/ImageView". Inside this **LinearLayout**, take **RelativeLayout** (RelativeLayout2) as first child and inside it Take two "**TextViews**". 


One with "**alignParentLeft=true**" and "**width = matchparent**". While the second one "**alignParenRight=true**" and "**width = wrap_content**". Now, what you need to is, in the first "**TextView**" set "**toLeftOf=@id/secondTextView**". 


 Now about the last "**TextView**". Just create a "**TextView**" inside the LinearLayout (that you created above with vertical orientation) and place it as second child. 
This will create a perfect layout. It is also an easy way to create one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Constraint Layout to achieve your desired UI. Below is the xml code to implement your UI.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        app:src="@drawable/def_doc"
        android:id="@+id/rvMsg_img"
        android:maxHeight="80dp"
        android:maxWidth="80dp"
        android:minHeight="80dp"
        android:minWidth="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/viewLine" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Kevin De Bruyne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rvMsg_name"
        android:textColor="@color/textBlack"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/rvMsg_img"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/rvMsg_img"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/rvMsg_img"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/rvMsg_time" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Hello developer. please check this message for long length. max length to 50 characters."
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rvMsg_last"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rvMsg_name"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/rvMsg_img"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/rvMsg_img"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/rvMsg_time"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="09:50 AM"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rvMsg_time"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/rvMsg_img"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/rvMsg_img"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/rvMsg_img"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/viewLine"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:background="#EAEAEA"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this layout structure

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_weight="1"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="centar"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="4">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BOLD TEXT"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sub Text" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Text" />
```

tru this code to achive gole.